# cannot insert tags in tumblr posts using imacros (code provided)

Tags: tumblr, imacros

Have a problem inserting tags in tumblr posts using imacros.

The code always worked fine but suddenly works no more.

Using the `datasource 1.csv` where I wrote 7 tags in the column 1, the script used to take one by one randomly but now it doesn't do that anymore.

I put the first tag `ggggg` on purpose to see if it is going to be inserted and it actually does, but all the others don't.

So the problem is in part of the code where imacros takes random tags from the datasource.

```
 SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
 TAB T=1
 SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ; 
 SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\1.csv
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:tag_editor
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*7 + 1); randomNumber;")
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT=ggggg
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*7 + 1); randomNumber;")
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!col1}}
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*7 + 1); randomNumber;")
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!col1}}
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*7 + 1); randomNumber;")
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!col1}}
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*7 + 1); randomNumber;")
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!VAR1}} 
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:tag_editor_input CONTENT={{!col1}}
 SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```

Comment: and again i cannot format the code properly here on stackoverflow: inserted 4 spaces before the code and still doesn't format properly well. Any help?

Comment: The new update of FireFox could be the issue. Revert to FF 31